# Fetching results from API - pagination and UX

Tags: javascript, pagination, user-experience

Let's say I have an endpoint that returns an array of 10k results. I want them to display in a table with pages included. What is the best way to do it considering UX?

1. Fetch everything at once and paginate
2. Fetch the results for the page user is visiting, display them and re-fetch everything

I know that the second option is slower, but it prevents fetching multiple times.
Which one would you go with?

PS And I know, this is probably not a great question when it comes to SO regulations, but I have little experience in the real world apps and wanted to know how it is done.

Comment: 10k results doesn't represent the actual workload required to gather the information nor the amount of data in each result.
no one in the real world would ever download it all to the client, if it's workload heavy to gather the information for a page - try to use caching wherever possible

Comment: @DimaVinogradov 10k results. Each one is a simple object with `id`, `title`, `description`. The overall response size is about 900kb.

Comment: Well, a person would page 1-2 pages back and forth top, if that doesn't yield enough information - filters should be applied
-bottom line, paginate it and retrieve only a single page per time

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you are correct in that it's not the best question when it comes to SO regs, but i feel its a valid one.

You should only load the items you need at the time, each request will go to fetch results. An example for 25 per page being: initially you may get results 0 - 25, then when user clicks page 2, you will fetch results 25-50 etc...

Comment: And let's say I have a smaller array, like 50 objects but it may grow. I decided to fetch 10 per page, but my pagination bar can fit up to 9 page numbers. How will I know how many I should fit there?

Comment: You'll do a quick sum to work out how many pages you need:  (in javascript: `let pagesCount = Math.ceil(resultsCount / perPage)`)

Comment: Yes, but it would require fetching all the data and count it. There is no point in fetching them per page then.

Comment: Your initial query to do the count would literally do just that, get a count of the results - not return them all.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't load the 10k  result at once.  You should load just some items with a limit (could be 10, 20, 50... up to you).
If you check your API, there is maybe a `limit` URL parameter and something called `start`? If yes, you can define how many result you want and from where to start. SO you will be able to 'send your pagination' to the API, and request only the 50 results from position 100.

Comment: Yes, there are `offset` and `limit` filters on this endpoint. I'm going to stick with fetching every time the user clicks the page.